# error clearing credentials remotely using PSEXEC cmd /c

Tags: batch-file, psexec

trying to clear credentials remotely using psexec but receive the following error when runnning elevated

```
@echo off
echo "Credential Clearer"

set /p asset="Enter IP Address: "

psexec \\%asset% cmd /c for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do  cmdkey /delete %H 

@echo off
pause
```

the for loop itself works fine when pasted into the command prompt but when i run it remotely using psexec the output is

H was unexpected at this time
cmd exited on ""ip address" with error code 1

Comment: No need to `"delim= "` as whitespace is the default delims in batch. i.e Tab, space... anyway, double up on `%` for metavariables in batch file. i.e `%%G` and `%%H`

Comment: Hi gerhard thanks for the reply - so i removed the = " to =" and added extra % but then received the error | was unexpected at this time

Comment: no psexec here for me to test, so you'll have to test for me. `psexec \\%asset% "cmd /c for /F ^"tokens=2^" %%a in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do  cmdkey /delete %%a"`

Comment: Hi there many thanks again for the reply - i executed that but received Starting cmd /c for /F ^tokens=2 %a in ('cmdkey /list | findstr Target') do cmdk

PsExec could not start cmd /c for /F ^tokens=2 %a in ('cmdkey /list | findstr Ta
rget') do cmdkey /delete %a on IPADDRESS:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Press any key to continue . . .




When i paste this straight into a command prompt you see it runs and removes credentials so was just trying to do it for remotely using psexec but doesnt seem to like the command

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, you cannot escape quotes within a quoted string, but if the outer quotes are really necessary, you could try to just escape the `=` like `... "tokens^=2" ...`...

Comment: @aschipfl oh brother, I did not realise what I was doing there. I was on my phone.